# sed regex remove special characters

Tags: regex, sed, special-characters

I have a file with several strings that come from an HTML formated text, so they have some HTML sequences that doesn't look good in a console interface. Here's an example:

```
Text1&#8482;
&#91;Text&#174;2&#93;
Text&#58;3
```

The thing I'm trying is to remove everything between & and ; so the text is readable again, like the following:

```
Text1
Text2
Text3
```

I'm actually trying to use sed to remove the extra characters:

```
sed 's#&*;##g' <file>
```

The problem is that it only removes the ; from the text strings.

The question then is, how should the regex expresion be coded in order to remove the extra chain: **&#[1-9]+;**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your regexp

```
sed 's#&*;##g' <file>
```

does not do what you think it does. The `*` character is a multiplier that says that the preceding character is repeated 0 or more times. The previous character is `&`, so this would match e.g. `&&&;` and `;` (`&` is written 0 times before `;`! This is what is matching in your test cases) but not what you want in this case.

You need to specify "*any* character" before the multiplier, which is represented by a single dot, `.`.

```
$ echo 'Text&#58;3' | sed 's#&.*;##g'
Text3
```

---

That was the first problem. The second is the concept of so called "greedy" matching: `sed` will see the first `&` and then try to match the largest string it can. If you have several HTML entities on a single line, this would be a problem since:

```
$ echo 'Text&#58;3 and some more text &aring; and end' | sed 's#&.*;##g'
Text and end
```

If you want to see a fix in the `sed` context, you could look for the ending character of the entity by matching any number of "*not* `;`" before a closing `;` by doing:

```
$ echo 'Text&#58;3 and some more text &aring; and end' | sed 's#&[^;]*;##g'
Text3 and some more text  and end
```

---

You will still have problems with legitimate uses of the ampersand sign (`&`) in the text (well, `&amp;` is the real "legitimate" use, but the real world is not always as parsable as the ideal one) and matching too much, but this explains why `sed` is behaving the way it does.

Comment: **sed 's#&[^;]*;##g'** works flawlessly.

Comment: @Peter: Good to hear! Note though as I said: if you have a stray single `&` in a line, the pattern might clear too much. If the input is well behaved, it won't be a problem. If not: more rigor is needed in the pattern, and quickly `sed`'s limits would make themselves known and other tools would be preferred.

Answer (score 0):

Is not it better to replace the codes with the actual characters?

```
echo 'Text1&#8482;
&#91;Text&#174;2&#93;
Text&#58;3' | perl -C -pe 's/&#([^;]*)/chr$1/eg'
```

Output:

```
Text1™;
[;Text®;2];
Text:;3
```